# How to stop Uploadify from displaying progress box

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify, image-uploading

Just as the title says, I can't seem to get Uploadify to stop displaying the progress box during upload. Here is what I have:

```
$('#imageupload').uploadify({
                'swf'      : 'scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : 'scripts/uploadify/uploadify.php',
                // Put your options here
                'buttonText' : 'Select Image',
                'uploadLimit' : 999,
                'overrideEvents' : ['onUploadProgress'],
                'multi' : false,
                'formData'      : {'yourid' : '<?=@(int)$_SESSION['user']?>'},
                'fileSizeLimit' : '2MB',
                'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.JPG; *jpeg',
                'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
                'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                    $("#imageupload").uploadify("settings", "formData", {'yourid' : $(".userid").attr("id")});
                    $(".imageuploadbox #imagepercent").css("display", "inline");
                },
                'onUploadSuccess' : function(file) {
                    var currenttime = new Date();
                    $("img#yourprofilepic").attr("src", "images/artist_pictures/thumbs/artist_8.jpg?"+currenttime);
                },
                'onUploadProgress' : function(file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal) {
                    var percentcomp = (100*(totalBytesTotal/totalBytesUploaded)).toFixed(0);
                    $('.imageuploadbox #imagepercent #percentcomplete').html(percentcomp);
                } 
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple try this:

Remove link to uploadify `css` and then add this in your css:

```
.uploadifyQueue
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! The only thing I'll add for people using this answer, the class is actually "uploadify-queue" and you don't need to unlink the uploadify.css file to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the names have changed, this one worked for me:

```
#upload_pc-queue{
    display:none;
}
```